# Are Character Sets Machine Dependent or Language Dependent?

Tags: c

I am learning C. C uses ASCII character set. Then I came to know about extended Ascii character set. Both of them prints the characters perfectly in there ranges. Is this because my local machine supports extended Ascii or C language or its Compiler supports extended Ascii ?

Comment: Your terminal supports the character set. C just sends data to it - it is up to it the terminal interpret those bytes

Comment: What do you mean by terminal ?

Comment: The same thing that you mean by "my local machine".

Comment: So its basically machine dependent. Is it ?

Comment: The windows/screen that you type into. Could be an xterm. Could be a vt100 terminal. Could be `cmd` in windows ....

Comment: It depends on the software that displays the characters or the underlying hardware (this is not so much true now but in the past it was)

Comment: C does not use ASCII, but your implementation might. You can read about the different character sets here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1

Comment: Is that the same in Java which uses Unicode?

Comment: Character sets are specified in standards e.g. the ASCII character set is named after the standard (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) that specifies it, Unicode is specified in ISO/IEC 10646. Hardware and software generally need to encode information (e.g. to exchange information with other hardware or software), and it is a design decision which standard encoding(s) a given system will support. The C standard specifies a C character set (which is used in C source) and implementations (compilers/libraries) map that to character set(s) used by the target environment.

Comment: Expanding on what @IljaEverilä said, it is quite unlikely that your C compiler uses ASCII. It is also quite unlikely that your C runtime uses ASCII and quite unlikely that your terminal uses ASCII and quite unlikely that your source code editor uses ASCII. The C compiler has default arguments for source character set and execution character set. The C runtime provides string functions that are affected by locale functions. All these can handle various character sets. Extended ASCII doesn't mean enough to be a useful term. It matters little that one character set is similar to another.

Comment: C vs Java: There is a vast difference between the design approaches. For C, they specifically avoided requiring a specific character set (instead, specifying an abstract basic character set and the implementation-defined `char` datatype). For Java, they specifically designed for the eventual UTF-16 encoding of Unicode (just like .NET, VB6, JavaScript, Win32 API, NTFS,....)

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays the only thing that defers on your "local machine", from other "local machines" it's the arch of your system(x32 or x64). That's why you see version of programms for both of these things.

Now for ASCII. Before ASCII there was no unique way of representations. ASCII came to set some default encoding for some "characters/letters/symbols". So ASCII comes more with your 'operating system' (sort of speak) than your "local machine". You can search and learn for alt keypad to understand some more of it.

So no. ASCII doesn't comes with C. Comes with the operating system because it's just a representation of various elements through software means.

Edit:
Don't confuse the ASCII with character encodings. They might be parts of the same topic but they are different. Encoding is a way of represanting a character that can not be represented with a byte (8-bits), and regarding this there are so many different unicode formats (UTF-8, ANSI, UCS-2 etc...). ASCII is 8-bit representation 'mapping' of a character that is out of the ASCII range (that's also the reason that the `sizeof(char)` in C (and in most systems) is `1`. Remember that we are talking about computer science atm, and everything is taking place with bits. So in for ASCII defines 128 char (0-127, 2^7). Unicode can define (if i am right) up to 2^21 -1. So i think that's the difference you are looking for to understand. Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't confuse the ASCII with character encodings. They might be parts of the same topic but they are different!...i will update my original post for more!